# How can I make a partial plot with healpix?

Tags: dictionary, healpy

I want to zoom in a particular region of the sky, and plot a map of only that region (e.g., the cold spot). How can I do this with healpix? I could not find options with mollview...etc.

Answer (score 1):

try using `gnomview`: you can choose the center coordinates (with `rot`) that you want to plot and a size in x and y (`xsize` and `ysize`). This will render a gnomonic projection of the part of the sky you are interested in.